# Downloaded font doesn't showing special characters

Tags: html, css, fonts

My font display a circle instead of special characters like "#" or "-"

I'm using "Intro font"

Do you have a solution ?

Please tell me that there's a solution .. ^^

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is [this font](http://www.fonts2u.com/intro.font).

Anyways, if you take a look for example at the font linked above, you can see which characters contains. For example these font doesn't have the `#` and `-` characters, so it can't display it, and instead it shows something like a "not found" character: a circle with a cross in your case.

Comment: Yes, I think it's this one .. Thank you !